# How to write/read to hardware in assembly

Tags: assembly, io, x86, hardware

what instruction or instructions would you use to write / read to hardware in x86 assembly? I need to write a driver (I am familiar with BUSes ports ect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you just looking for [IN](http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/i.html#IN) and [OUT](http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/o.html#OUT)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget ins and outs, if for no other reason than completeness.

Comment: By ins and outs of course I mean INS* (INput String from port) and OUTS* (OUTput String to port). The * denotes B(yte), W(ord), D(ouble) and Q(word) port widths.